# Create symlink with existing directory structure in new location

Tags: bash, shell, find, ln

I'm using

```sh
find source -name 'Archive.folder'
```

which outputs:

```
source/1/Archive.folder
source/2/Archive.folder
...
```

to find all folders named Archive.folder in the source folder. Now I want to link them to a new location 
`/var/CommuniGate/Accounts`. How can I do that?
I found the following solution but it doesn't work, it just links the source folder, not the found folders.

```sh
find source -name 'Archive.folder' | xargs -0 ln -s -t /var/CommuniGate/Accounts
```

The symlinks should be created like this:

```
/var/CommuniGate/Accounts/source/1/Archive.folder
/var/CommuniGate/Accounts/source/1/Archive.folder
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
find source -name Archive.folder -print0 |
xargs -0 -iDIR sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/CommuniGate/Accounts/$(dirname DIR); ln -s -t /var/CommuniGate/Accounts/$(dirname DIR) $PWD/DIR'
```

That works for my simple test case.

Comment: I'm getting ```ln: failed to create symbolic link 'test/Archive.folder': File exists
``` after the first file. It fails to copy the folder structure in source. Otherwise it seems to work.

Comment: It seems to ignore the 1,2,3,.. folders from my example.